# Reorder your dataframe by reordering one column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, indexing

Having a dataframe which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

I wonder how to rearange the dataframe when having a different order in one column that one wants to apply to all the others, for example having changed the A column in this example?

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A3', 'A0', 'A2', 'A1'],
                     'B': ['B3', 'B0', 'B2', 'B1'],
                     'C': ['C3', 'C0', 'C2', 'C1'],
                     'D': ['D3', 'D0', 'D2', 'D1']},
                     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Is df2 the final results or you want index 1,2,3 of df2 to order as df2 index 0?

Comment: sorry, it posted before I finished editing. I want all the columns to change order according to the A one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing via `set_index`, `reindex` and `reset_index`. Assumes your values in `A` are unique, which is the only case where such a transformation would make sense.

```
L = ['A3', 'A0', 'A2', 'A1']

res = df1.set_index('A').reindex(L).reset_index()

print(res)

    A   B   C   D
0  A3  B3  C3  D3
1  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A1  B1  C1  D1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the key parameter from the sorted function:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])


key = {'A3': 0, 'A0': 1, 'A2' : 2, 'A1': 3}
df1['A'] = sorted(df1.A, key=lambda e: key.get(e, 4))

print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A3  B0  C0  D0
1  A0  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A1  B3  C3  D3
```

By changing the values of key, you can set whatever order you want.

**UPDATE**

If want you want is to alter the order of the other columns based on the new order of `A`, you could try something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A3', 'A0', 'A2', 'A1'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                   index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

key = [df1.A.values.tolist().index(k) for k in df2.A]
df2.B = df2['B'][key].tolist()
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A3  B3  C0  D0
1  A0  B0  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A1  B1  C3  D3
```

To alter all the columns just apply the above for each column. Somthing like this:

```
for column in df2.columns.values:
    if column != 'A':
        df2[column] = df2[column][key].tolist()
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A3  B3  C3  D3
1  A0  B0  C0  D0
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A1  B1  C1  D1
```

Answer (score 1):

did you mean to sort 1 specific row? if so, use:

```
df1.iloc[:1] = df1.iloc[:1].sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False)
print(df1)
```

for all columns use:

```
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=0,ascending=False)
```

for specific columns use the iloc function.

Comment: yes, the second option is what i should get, sorry, my network messed the post up for a few minutes.

Comment: No problem. Hope that helped. :)